# Allowing any type in the Open panel in a document-based application

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit, nsopenpanel, launch-services

I'm writing a document-based Mac application that can open any type. My application receives dropped files of any type on its Dock tile successfully, but when I choose Open from the File menu, all files are grayed out.

It's the standard Open item that comes with the template; I haven't put anything special behind it.

Here's the relevant part of my Info.plist:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Any file</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeOSTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>****</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>LSTypeIsPackage</key>
        <false/>
        <key>NSDocumentClass</key>
        <string>MyDocument</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

I have a custom document controller; here's its implementation.

```
- (Class) documentClassForType:(NSString *)documentTypeName {
    return [MyDocument class];
}

- (NSString *) typeForContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)inAbsoluteURL error:(NSError **)outError {
    return @"Any file";
}
```

These methods are not called at any time unless I drop a file on the Dock tile.

Answer (score 1):

In your `NSDocumentController` subclass, override `runModalOpenPanel:forTypes:` and just call super with nil for the `types` array. That will enable all file names in the `NSOpenPanel`.